# SSL connection error ONLY when I test my rails app (localhost:3000) on chrome. It works on firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, and for some reason, I am unable to test the sample app on Google Chrome. I test it by first running the rails server, then going to "localhost:3000" on the browser. When I run the rails server, and go to localhost:3000 on Firefox, it works fine and I can use the app. When then on Chrome, I get:

"SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error."

In CMD (I use windows 7), after I run the rails server, and I attempt to go to localhost:3000, I get these errors:

```
14:22:19] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
14:22:19] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
14:22:19] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3064 port=3000
14:22:48] ERROR bad URI `2r?f?\x06\x01\x1Akh/'f??\x10'?j?<\x00\x00H?'.
14:22:48] ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00?\x01\x00\x00?\x03\x02Q"\x7F?\x18??@?X?F???#K???\x17?#?e??4?k`?\x00\x00H?'.
14:22:49] ERROR bad URI `?'.
14:22:49] ERROR bad URI `??x\x1F?\x06??M??IL?C\x00\x00*\x00?\x00?\x00?\x009\x008\x00?\x005\x00E\x00D\x00f\x003\x002\x00?\x00A\x00\x05\x00\x
```

Comment: Clear your browser's cookies and try doing the same thing over.. this  is a known problem with respect to SSL connections in RoR..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. As @looseseal_90 said in comments, you should try to clear the cookies and reload the page.

(I know that everyone can read a comment, but it would be better the question to have the answer :-)